# How to install the PayPal API-Certificate on Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, integration, paypal

I have implemented the PayPal express checkout function on my website, by using PayPal API for SOAP. The integration in ASP.NET and the communication with the PayPal sandbox service https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0 was easy.
On sandbox I have used username, password and API-Signature for authentication, but I can't find a API-Signature in my PayPal profile. The 2nd Option in the API-Authorization displayed username, password and a API-Certificate (*.pem file) only.

The integration guide describing how can install the certificate on Windows Server 2003, but not 2008 R2. The Windows Tool Kit doesn't work on Server 2008 R2.
And I can't use a second certificate, because I use already a SSL certificate on my server as server certificate.

Does anyone have any idea how I get a API-Signature?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has recently updated the user-interface of developer site.

Here is the instruction how to get API-Signature.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi,thanks for you answer. My problem is not the sandbox, this works fine. I need a API-Signature for PayPal prod system and but the PayPal user interface of the real (life) PayPal profile settings doesn't has an option to get a API-Signature. I can get a API-Certificate only.

Comment: You cannot have both Signature and Certificate in a single account. You need to delete the Certificate in order to create new Signature. FYI: Signature is a PayPal's prefer way of access API.